# how to iterate between last 300 rows of column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
x = pd.read_csv(filename)

if abs(x["b"].values[-1] - x["a"].values[-300]) <= 2:
    print('less than')
    x1=x.iloc[-300:]
```

**this piece of code calculating difference between row -300 and -1, its working well , but i want to add more condition if difference between row number -300 and -1 is greater than 2 i want to check difference  for row number -299 and -2 and do then for -298 and -2 , do this ten times and every time change of one point , and if achieve difference less than 2  then  stop process and cut data piece between these two points and if did not find less difference less than 2 then print condition not find **

if someone have good idea please share here.

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should od it:

```
i, j = -1, -300

for _ in range(1, 11):
    if abs(x["b"].values[i] - x["a"].values[j]) <= 2:
        print('less than')
        x1 = x.iloc[j:]
        break
    i -= -1
    j += 1
else:
    pass
    # here you can write what happens if condition is not met
```

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

i, j = -1, -5

x = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0, 20, 2),
                  'b': [16]*10})

for _ in range(1, 6):
    print abs(x["b"].values[i] - x["a"].values[j])
    if abs(x["b"].values[i] - x["a"].values[j]) <= 2:
        print('less than')
        x1 = x.iloc[j:]
        break
    i -= -1
    j += 1
else:
    pass

x1
#    a   b
#7  14  16
#8  16  16
#9  18  16
```

Comment: I tried this but got error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @waqarali Can you share an example of your data, this code works fine for me on the provided example.

Comment: thanks your piece of code works and my problem solved